# Laravel - Data not stored on database, image upload failed

Tags: php, image, laravel, intervention

I have a post with title, texts & image. But I can't save the image path to database. Here is my code.

```
public function save(Request $request, Post $post)
{       

    $this->validate(request(),
    [
        'title' => 'required',
        'image' => 'image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg'
    ]);

    if($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $fileNameExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileName = pathinfo($fileNameExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $fileExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore = $fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$fileExt;
        Image::make($file)->resize(600, 600)->save( public_path('media/' . $fileNameToStore));
        $post->image = $fileNameToStore;

    auth()->user()->publish(
        new Post(request(['title', 'text', 'image']))
    );
}
    return redirect ('/');
}
```

But it does not store image path to `image` column of database. Instead tmp data like `C:\xampp\tmp\phpC549.tmp` stored. What is wrong here?

Comment: I do not see (sorry if there is) where you save the model

Comment: Sorry not clear. I have a method to publish the post `public function publish(Post $post)
    {
        $this->posts()->save($post);
    }`

Comment: What if you change this line `$post->image = $fileNameToStore;` by this one `$post->image = public_path('media/' . $fileNameToStore);` ?

Comment: It says `Can't write image data to path (C:\xampp\htdocs\..\public\/media/)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the save code

```
 auth()->user()->publish(
        new Post(request(['title', 'text', 'image']))
    );
```

to

```
 auth()->user()->publish(
        new Post([
'title'=>$request->title,
'text'=>$request->text,
])
    );
```

since image val already set inside hasfile if condition

Sample Image path

```
public function addBlogCategoryPost(BlogCategoryRequest $request) {



        $destinationPath = 'iamge path';
        $data = [
            'category_name' => $request->category_name,
            'category_description' => $request->category_description,
            'seo_url' => $request->seo_url,
            'meta_title' => $request->meta_title,
            'meta_description' => $request->meta_description,
            'meta_keywords' => $request->meta_keywords,
            'meta_author' => $request->meta_author,
        ];

        if ($request->hasFile('category_image')) {

            $file = $request->file('category_image');
            //move iamge to folder
            $fileName = str_random(30) . '.' . $file->clientExtension();
            $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
            $data['category_image'] = $fileName;
        }

            $addTag = BlogCategory::create($data);



        if ($addTag) {
            return $addTag;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Umm. But why this does not save the image path, while title & text are saved?

Comment: Are there any other methods to store the path without specifying $request variable?

Comment: Can't I resolve it on ` auth()->user()->publish(
        new Post(request(['title', 'text', 'image']))
    );` without specifying `$request` for each entity? I removed if condition but not solved. From where temp data is stored for `image` column?

Comment: i have not used that type as per me if you use image like that then it will take temp path

Comment: you can try request without iamge